# Getting & Setting localStorage to Same TextArea?

Tags: jquery

I have three HTML pages designed to be like an interactive set of exercises. Each exercise builds on the last.

First, the user edits text in "ExSixTextBox", and then saves it to localStorage by clicking button ID "ExSixSaveWork" (see jQuery underneath). This works fine. Then - the Ex7 HTML textbox Gets the Ex6 localStorage, and adds the Ex7 text underneath it. This works fine.

*Then*, I want Exercise 8 to Get what user has done from Exercise 7 (which includes 6), and have it appear above the Ex8-specific text.

The problem is under "//EXERCISE 6 SAVE WORK TO POPULATE FOR EXERCISE 7". To Set item "ExSevenWorkData" (ready for Ex8), the HTML textarea ID has already been used to retrieve the text from Exercise 6. So there is a clash on the Exercise 7 textbox's ID.

I thought a logical solution would be to give the textarea from Exercise 7 multiple ID's, but it looks like you can't do that.

Could you please help?

```
// EXERCISE SIX HTML

<textarea id="ExSixTextBox" cols="80" rows="40">
"Exercise Six Stencil goes here"
</textarea>
<button id="ExSixSaveWork">Save Your Work</button>


//EXERCISE SEVEN HTML

<textarea id="ExSixToSevenMerge" cols="80" rows="40">
</textarea>
<button id="ExSevenSaveWork">Save Your Work</button>


//EXERCISE EIGHT HTML

<textarea id="ExSevenToEightMerge" cols="80" rows="40">
</textarea>
<button id="ExEightSaveWork">Save Your Work</button>


//sets text that displays when user clicks "SaveWork" buttons.

var saveConfirm = "Your work has been saved! Exercise complete.";


//EXERCISE 6 SAVE WORK TO POPULATE FOR EXERCISE 7

$("#ExSixSaveWork").click(function() {
 $('#ExSixSaveWork').replaceWith(document.createTextNode(saveConfirm)).show();
 localStorage. setItem('ExSixWorkData',document.getElementById('ExSixTextBox').value);
});

$("#ExSixToSevenMerge").val(localStorage.getItem('ExSixWorkData')+('\n\n\nCONCEIVING STEPS:\n\n1. \n2. \n3. \n\n1. \n2. \n3. \n\n1. \n2. \n3. \n\n1. \n2. \n3. \n\n'));


// EXERCISE 7 SAVE WORK TO POPULATE FOR EXERCISE 8

$("#ExSevenSaveWork").click(function() {
 $('#ExSevenStep4').replaceWith(document.createTextNode(saveConfirm)).show();
 localStorage. setItem('ExSevenWorkData',document.getElementById('***UMM?***').value);  *** PROBLEM IS HERE, HOW DO I SPECIFY WHAT ELEMENT TO GET BY ID
});

$("#ExSevenToEightMerge").val(localStorage.getItem('ExSevenWorkData')+('\n\nGRATITUDE STATEMENT:\n'));
```

Comment: Exercise 7 `<textarea>` id - `ExSixToSevenMerge`

Comment: I don't understand... that is what the ID currently is.

Comment: There can't be any clash. You can use that ID again.

Comment: Thanks, what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#ExSevenSaveWork").click(function() {
 $('#ExSevenStep4').replaceWith(document.createTextNode(saveConfirm)).show();
 localStorage. setItem('ExSevenWorkData',document.getElementById('ExSixToSevenMerge').value);
});
```

Or

```
$("#ExSevenSaveWork").click(function() {
     $('#ExSevenStep4').replaceWith(document.createTextNode(saveConfirm)).show();
     localStorage. setItem('ExSevenWorkData',$('#ExSixToSevenMerge').val());
});
```

If you are using jQuery, why not try `$('#Id').val()` instead of `document.getElementById('Id').value`

Comment: Will you marry me? :P
Thank you! That worked perfectly.